# simple dc circuit question

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I am suing superposition to solve for IR3.

Professor said there is no current flow through 1 kilo ohm resistor. He said it is because it is in parallel with the voltage source. I am confused. If a resistor is in parallel with the voltage source can I ignore the resistor?

Why is there no current through in this case exactly?

Comment: The 8mA and IR3 are   independent of the shunt current in IR1, so R1  has no effect on n current in R3.... is what he meant. So yes IR1 can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You are using superposition to solve a circuit by solving each source separately, then adding the results. When you solve the circuit for a given source, you have to remove each OTHER source from the circuit. For a current source, you do this by turning it into an OPEN circuit (i.e. no wire); for a voltage source you do this by turning it into a SHORT circuit (i.e. a wire).

So in this circuit, WHEN you are solving the circuit for the CURRENT source, you turn the voltage source into a wire. Then, since the 1k resistor is in parallel with a zero-ohm wire, it has no effect FOR THAT PART of the solution (when solving the current source.) So you can remove it for that purpose only.

For the OTHER part of the solution, when you are solving the circuit for the VOLTAGE source, with the current source removed, the 1k resistor will carry current and can NOT be removed.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is wrong. Of course there are some currents passing through that resistor. My simulator is showing 24mA will pass. Check your maths please.

Comment: The point, though, is that the current in \$R_1\$ doesn't matter (or effect) the rest of the circuit analysis. I think that's the instructor's point here.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this simplifies how to look at things. I've grounded the left side of your schematic, below. (We can do this for exactly one node of our choice.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwqUDY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think, now, that you can see that \$R_1\$ doesn't really have any impact at all on \$I_{\text{R}_3}\$. So you can ignore that part. I think that's the point your instructor wanted you to understand. You can ignore \$R_1\$ since it doesn't affect the rest of the circuit.

At this point, all you need to worry about is \$V_\text{X}\$. Putting out-flowing currents on the left side of the equation and in-flowing currents on the right side (which must equal each other, of course), we find:

$$\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_2}+\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_3}+8\:\text{mA}=\frac{24\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_3}$$

Once you solve that for \$V_\text{X}\$, you can find the value for \$I_{\text{R}_3}\$.

$$V_\text{X}=\frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3}\cdot \left(24\:\text{V}-R_2\cdot I_1\right)$$

Therefore,

$$I_{\text{R}_3}=-\frac{V_x}{R_3}=-\frac{\left(24\:\text{V}-R_2\cdot I_1\right)}{R_2+R_3}$$

It's not too complicated, really.